# File Deletion using Applescript. A bad script?

Tags: applescript, directory

I'm very new to Applescript but have used other scripting languages over the last five years.  I wrote a quick script that deletes some files/directories based upon file name matches and modification date.  I did also test it a few times but I'm now under the impression that it is either badly written or dangerous, in the sense that it may delete more than necessary.

If you're a pro scripter, can you please tell me if there's anything wrong with my script? Is it unsafe?  I've been led to believe that after speaking to a colleague who believes it's done some 'damage'.

Here's the script:

```
set my_path to "Macintosh HD:Users:infmz:Backups"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (every item of folder my_path whose modification date is less than ((get current date) - 4 * days) and name contains "backup_id")
        empty trash
    end tell
```

Specifically, I am trying to delete backup folders that are older than three days.  All such folders contain the string "backup_id" in their names.

Comment: @Laas please see my comment to Philip's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entirety of the script, then I would say the one "unsafe" item that really jumps out to me is that you are not parsing the folder path to ensure the script isn't being directed to a vital folder, like "Macintosh HD:System:" or "Macintosh HD:Library:".

The other thing is that I don't think the script does a good enough job parsing files before deleting. This is more a matter of approach, but if it were me, I would generate a list of initial target files first (see ["Get full directory contents with AppleScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097263)), and then parse that list for actual targets for deletion.

Also, I would generate a log of actions taken and remove the "empty trash" command to allow the user a chance to double-check the actions of the script before final deletion.

It would be helpful to describe what damage was observed by the other user.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into your suggestions.  In order to keep the machine clean I included the empty trash with confidence that my script is picking up the right files/folders and nothing else.  The damage was that basically, the whole RAID that my script was acting on fell off of our network.  However, this was later shown to be a power issue, whereby an outage caused the raid and others machines wired into the same power strip to turn off.

Comment: Emptying the trash may be convenient, but you also have no idea what else is in there. That action should be left up to the user, not you.

Comment: That's true.  I think really I need to delete them for good without emptying the trash.  Permanently deleting is important as the RAID was getting full, displaying a warning message in this respect, roughly the same time with the outage!  This is why I added the empty trash, so that it doesn't fill up again.  Regarding the path, then on the original it went something like "Backup_RAID::Archives", how do you suggest I parse it?  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually there is not much the script can do about securing the folder path. It is already hard-coded into the script. One would have to edit the script in order to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If the RAID suffered power loss, then probably that did more damage than your script. Reading through, I did not notice anything out of ordinary.

As to what @Philip pointed out - Trash is meant to be the *undo* system for file deletions. So purging it automatically w/o use consent is kind of unpolite.

If the backups are on a different volume (as I understood, it is some shared RAID), you could look into how to [empty trash for single volume only](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070310205600735).

That link also has an example how to first confirm the emptying with the user.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Thank you Laas, that's what I thought.  I would've been better off permanently deleting the files instead of sending them to the trash and then emptying that.