# Batch Convert *.numbers to *.csv AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I was looking for a script that would batch convert all *.numbers files in a given folder to *.csv files.

I found the following on GitHub and added an additional line as suggested in the comments suggestion. When I run the script, Numbers launches and opens the test file from the folder specified - but the file is not exported. Numbers just stays open and terminal errors out with:

> /Users/Shared/Untitled.scpt: execution error: Numbers got an error: Invalid key form. (-10002)

The script (located in /Users/Shared) has the following permissions:
-rwxr-xr-x

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    set theFilePath to POSIX file (item 1 of argv)
    set theFolder to theFilePath as alias
    tell application "Finder" to set theDocs to theFolder's items

    -- Avoid export privilege problem
    set privilegeFile to (theFolder as text) & ".permission"
    close access (open for access privilegeFile)

    repeat with aDoc in theDocs
        set docName to aDoc's name as text
        if docName ends with ".numbers" then
            set exportName to (theFolder as text) & docName
            set exportName to exportName's text 1 thru -9
            set exportName to (exportName & "csv")
            tell application "Numbers"
                open aDoc
                delay 5 -- may need to adjust this higher
                tell front document
                    export to file exportName as CSV
                    close
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat

end run
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use `tell application "System Events" to set theDocs to theFolder's items whose name extension = "numbers"` instead of `tell application "Finder" to set theDocs to theFolder's items` as **System Events** is much faster than **Finder** and `whose name extension = "numbers"` eliminates the need for `if docName ends with ".numbers" then` _statement_ as only file with the `numbers` extension are passed to `theDocs`. `set exportName to exportName's text 1 thru -9` should be `set exportName to exportName's text 1 thru -8` so the `.` is not removed.  Cont...

Comment: ...Cont. With those changes and the removal of `privilegeFile` lines the _code_, it works just fine for me.  I also set `delay` to `1`.

Comment: Also if the output in **Terminal** of `file /Users/Shared/Untitled.scpt` **is** `/Users/Shared/Untitled.scpt AppleScript compiled` and not `/Users/Shared/Untitled.scpt a /usr/bin/osascript script text executable, ASCII text` then that is a problem!

Comment: Thank you @user3439894 for your comments. I attempted to modify the script based on your recommendations. With the removal of the 'if' statement (due to the 'whose name extension = "numbers" addition) I also removed the 'end if' at the end. After the modification in Script Editor I chose 'Compile the Script' and then exported as *.scpt. Terminal errors out with 'Invalid key form. (-10002)' - this is on macOS Catalina.

Script here:
https://pastebin.com/ZtFiAXL2

Comment: Also, I attempt to execute the script with the following:

`osascript /Users/Shared/zzz23.scpt /Users/Shared/csv_files`

Comment: The _code_ needs to be saved as a plain text format file, make the file executable, then use it in **Terminal** as a standalone executable!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for that, unfortunately, that doesn’t work anymore.

This line

```
tell application "System Events" to set theDocs to theFolder's items whose name extension = "numbers"
```

Gets the following error:

```
execution error: Can’t make file "file.numbers" of application "System Events" into the expected type. (-1700)
```

- macOs Big Sur Versio 11.01
- automator version 2.10
- Numbers version 10.3.5

Inspired by this thread and those articles [Exporting Numbers Documents](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/document-export.html) and [Get full directory contents with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097263/get-full-directory-contents-with-applescript)

The following code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

log "Start"

property exportFileExtension : "csv"

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set sourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select directory."
    set fileList to name of every file of sourceFolder
end tell

set the defaultDestinationFolder to sourceFolder

repeat with documentName in fileList
    log "documentName: " & documentName

    set fullPath to (sourceFolder as text) & documentName
    log "fullPath: " & fullPath

    if documentName ends with ".numbers" then
        set documentName to text 1 thru -9 of documentName

        tell application "Finder"
            set newExportItemName to documentName & "." & exportFileExtension
            set incrementIndex to 1
            repeat until not (exists document file newExportItemName of defaultDestinationFolder)
                set newExportItemName to ¬
                    documentName & "-" & (incrementIndex as string) & "." & exportFileExtension
                set incrementIndex to incrementIndex + 1
            end repeat
        end tell
        set the targetFileHFSPath to ¬
            (defaultDestinationFolder as string) & newExportItemName

        tell application "Numbers"
            launch
            open fullPath
            with timeout of 1200 seconds
                export front document to file targetFileHFSPath as CSV
            end timeout
            close
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: This solution works almost perfect for me. In bigsur I had problems opening the files in numbers this way, Numbers was giving opening errors. I opened the files with

`tell application "Finder"
   open fullPath
end tell`

and removed the open fullPath in Numbers to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did and works for me in **macOS High Sierra**:

1. In **Terminal**:

```
touch numb2csv; open -e numb2csv; chmod +x numb2csv
```

• This creates an empty **ASCII Text** *file* named **numb2csv**.
     • Opens, by default, **numb2csv** in **TextEdit**.
     • Makes the **numb2csv** *file* executable.

2. Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into the opened **numb2csv** *file*.
3. Save and close the **numb2csv** *file*.
4. In **Terminal** executed the **numb2csv**  executable *file*, e.g.:

```
./numb2csv "$HOME/Documents"
```

- This created a **CSV** *file* of the same *name* as each **Numbers** *document* in my **Documents** *folder*, not traversing any nested *folders*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    set theFilePath to POSIX file (item 1 of argv)
    set theFolder to theFilePath as alias
    tell application "System Events" to set theDocs to theFolder's items whose name extension = "numbers"

    repeat with aDoc in theDocs
        set docName to aDoc's name as text
            set exportName to (theFolder as text) & docName
            set exportName to exportName's text 1 thru -8
            set exportName to (exportName & "csv")
            tell application "Numbers"
                launch
                open aDoc
                repeat until exists document 1
                    delay 3
                end repeat
                tell front document
                    export to file exportName as CSV
                    close
                end tell
            end tell
    end repeat

    tell application "Numbers" to quit

end run
```

- **NOTE:** As *coded*, this will overwrite an existing **CSV** *file* of the same name as each **Numbers** *file* processed, if they already exist. Additional *coding* required if wanting to not overwrite existing *files*

If you receive the **Script Error**:

> Numbers got an error: The document “name” could not be exported as “name”. You don’t have permission.

It is my experience that the **Numbers** *document* was not fully opened prior to being exported and that increasing the *value* of the `delay` *command* resolves this issue. This is of course assuming that one actually has *write permissions* in the *folder* the target **Numbers** *documents* exists.

Or one can introduce an *error handler* within the `tell front document` *block* which, if my theory is right about the target *document* not being fully loaded before the export, will give additional time, e.g.:

**Change:**

```
tell front document
    export to file exportName as CSV
    close
end tell
```

**To:**

```
tell front document
    try
        export to file exportName as CSV
        close
    on error
        delay 3
        export to file exportName as CSV
        close
    end try
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The primary *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). See included example directly above.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

user3439894's answer works with a few change:

- `exists document 1` => `number of documents > 0`